# append html on javascript animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, append

I am trying to figure out why the fade in and out of a dialog box in this code is not working properly.

What I'm trying to do is having a fade in and out on click.

This is my code

CSS:

```
.modal 
{
display: block;
overflow: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 99;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
outline: 0;
background-image: url('/assets/images/pixel.png');
opacity: 1;
}

.modal-dialog 
{
max-width: 600px;
background-color: white;
z-index: 99;
min-height: 200px;
opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.modal-dialog .active 
{
opacity: 1;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #999;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
-moz-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;

}
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-modal]', function(e){
e.preventDefault();

$('body').addClass('modal-open');

$('body').append("<div class='modal'></div>").addClass('active');

    $('.modal').append("<div class='modal-dialog'></div>")

    $('.modal-dialog').html("<div class='modal-inner generic-    content'></div>").addClass('active');
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'll show you how to add fadeOut() and fadeIn() to your dialog, but I didn't fix the style of your dialog as I didn't have time, but I hope you'll fix it by yourself.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <input type="button" id="open" value="Open"/>
</body>
```

JS:

```
$('body').addClass('modal-open');

    $('body').append("<div class='modal' style='display:none'></div>").addClass('active');

    $('.modal').append("<div class='modal-dialog'></div>")

    $('.modal-dialog').html("<div class='modal-inner generic-content'>/div>").addClass('active');


$('#open').on('click', function(e){        
    $(".modal").fadeIn(400);
    $(this).focusout();
    $("body").focusin();
});

$("body").keydown(function(evt){
    if(evt.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $(".modal").fadeOut(400);
    }
});
```

or, to fade out on click, you can use this in the place of key down:

```
$("div").click(function(evt){
    $(".modal").fadeOut(400);
});
```

Here, when you click "open" dialog will be shown in fadeIn animation. fadeIn(400) ... 400 means the time period given to the animation to fade in the dialog.

And when click on the body and press enter key (KeyCode = 13), it'll fade out and hide. You also can use the ESC to close it(keycode = 27).

Here is the [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/holo/4Hut3/2/).

I guess you can improve your CSS to show this dialog as a dialog.